# Iterate through a list of list in python

Tags: python, json, list, nested

I am reading the following nested dictionary in json from an API

```
{
 "result": [{
               "short_description": "I am getting bluescreen error",
               "sys_id": "39b5f8c2376ede007520021a54990e5c",
               "opened_at": "2016-04-04 05:19:53",
               "number":"INC0258523"
             },
             {
               "short_description": "laptop crashed with a blue screen",
               "sys_id": "da0095380f43d200a4f941fce1050eeb",
               "opened_at":"2016-04-25 06:33:52",
               "number":"INC0259067"
             }, 
             {
               "short_description": "Laptop not booting",
               "sys_id": "ecf9c9b00f43d200a4f941fce1050e17",
               "opened_at": "2016-04-25 06:07:16",
               "number": "INC0259061"
             }]
}
```

**I need to filter the data based on two from and two dates. `opened_at` is the value containing the date info.**

My attempt so far is as follows

```
    url = "http://ip:port/api"

    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(response.read())
    print type(data)
    pattern = 'opened_at'
    element = '2016-04-25 06:33:19'
    with open('D:/Output.csv', 'wb') as f:  
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, data['result'][0].keys()) 
        w.writeheader()
        print type(data['result'])
        for key in data['result']:
            for v, val in data['result'].items():
                if v == pattern and val == element:
                    w.writerow(v)
```

I get the below error on running the code

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I know that the type of data['result'] is a list.Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: give some required output, would be easier...

Comment: output should be a csv file with contents only between two certain dates. Say I give 04-04-2016 , then the csv file should contain records only made on 04-04-2016.

Answer (score 4):

`data['result']` is a list of dictionaries, you should iterate on it like follows:

```
for d in data['result']:
    for k, v in d.items():
```

Comment: Sorry but I am not getting the desired output from it. Nothing is getting written to the output file.

Comment: are you sure your element variable contains a value present in your json ? It is not the case in your example.

Answer (score 1):

you need this

```
import json
al = """
{
 "result": [{
               "short_description": "I am getting bluescreen error",
               "sys_id": "39b5f8c2376ede007520021a54990e5c",
               "opened_at": "2016-04-04 05:19:53",
               "number":"INC0258523"
             },
             {
               "short_description": "laptop crashed with a blue screen",
               "sys_id": "da0095380f43d200a4f941fce1050eeb",
               "opened_at":"2016-04-25 06:33:52",
               "number":"INC0259067"
             }, 
             {
               "short_description": "Laptop not booting",
               "sys_id": "ecf9c9b00f43d200a4f941fce1050e17",
               "opened_at": "2016-04-25 06:07:16",
               "number": "INC0259061"
             }]
}
"""
myjson = json.loads(al)
for val in myjson['result']:
    print val['opened_at']
    for key, value in val.items():#change it to keys if required
```

Comment: That's exactly what I have posted 5 min ago, except that you renamed OP variables...

Answer (score 0):

Actually "Result" is a dictionnary. You can recognize a dictionnary in Python by the "{" and "}" it is circled with.
So here it is a dictionnary of a list of dictionnaries !